# Read integer or doubles from JsonArray in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have to receive a json file from my server and I need to parse it. Until now, I receive all fields as strings:

```
{"key1":"12", "key2":"23.5",...}
```

I read it like this:

```
JsonArray root = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetArray();

for (uint i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("id"));
            int state = Convert.ToInt32(root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("state"));
 .....
```

But now, I receive some of the data as integers or doubles and I don't know how to parse it in the way I did until now because there is no method to return an int with a string given.

```
{"key1":12, "key2":23.5,...}
```

Comment: So, your problem is that given a string, you don't know if it is a double or an int?

Comment: You've given an example of the string case, but we don't know what your JSON looks like for numbers or what you're trying to decide...

Comment: Sorry I forgot. I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Json` does not allow you to see the difference between integers and floating point numbers. You might want to try Json.NET, which does:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse("{\"key1\":12, \"key2\":23.5 }");

foreach (JProperty node in parsed.Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", node.Name, node.Value.Type);
}
```

The output:

```
key1: Integer
key2: Float
```

Of course, there are other libraries out there that can deal with JSON, but at least Json.NET works with Silverlight and supports your scenario.

Comment: Does this library have a method to find an element? I mean, If I want the "ID" element, do I have to iterate through all of them to find it? Or it has something like GetElement("ID")?

Comment: If you look at my sample, to specifically get `key1`, you could access it by `parsed["key1"] `.

Comment: I updated my code and I have problems with JObjec.Parse part. With your string, it works but with my json string it doesn't: [
    {
        "id": 34,
        "state": 0,
        "sensor_size": 5}] It gives an exception, but not why. I will check

Comment: I get {"Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."}

Comment: That's correct; you're trying to parse something different than the JSON from your question. `JObject` assumes it's an object, and you're giving it an array. Try `JToken.Parse()`; because it's an array, you also need to access the correct element: `parsed[0]["id"]`.

Comment: It worked. I have to change to JToken and a bit more and now it works. Thank you!